# Does the JVM keep its time synced with the OS?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, ntp

I am working on an application which is time-centric. My code frequently calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.

So I want to make sure these timestamp calls are perfectly synced with the OS. When and how does the JVM sync its clock? At startup or every time I call those two methods?

My OS time is perfectly synced with NTP servers.

Comment: The JVM does not have its own clock. Both these methods end up doing systemcalls to ask to OS for the time.

Comment: I don't think `nanoTime` has any relation to absolute timestamps, nor can it be synchronized via NTP. This is just an internal CPU counter.

Comment: @Thilo Is ```System.currentTimeMillis()``` synchronized via OS and NTP?

Comment: It gets the current time from the OS via a system call. If that OS clock is synchronized to NTP or anything else depends how the OS is configured.

Comment: Cool, I will use ```System.currentTimeMillis()``` from now onwards. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an implementation for every OS, for both `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.

A few examples of `System::nanoTime` implementations:

[On Linux](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp#l1344)

[On windows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/os/windows/os_windows.cpp#l945)

[On AIX](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/os/aix/os_aix.cpp#l1087)

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer with some actual resources.

Answer (score 6):

The time is provided by OS. JVM has no own clock instead of OS clock.

Comment: Could you back your answer by providing some links?